# XGBoost Bad Allocation

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

When loading an XGBoost model and running it I get the following error:

```
XGBoostError: bad allocation
```

I read it might be a memory problem, I have 32Gb of RAM and the model is quite small. I only have 8Gb of memory on my C: drive which might be causing the problem?

Code below:

```
def workflow_funnel(embeddings, model, funneldf):
        xvalid_count_source = embeddings.transform(funneldf['cleaned_original_text'].apply(lambda x: np.str_(x)))
        funnel_predictions = model.predict(xvalid_count_source)

funnel_model = xgboost.Booster(model_file = project_directory + language+funnel_model_load)
```

Full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XGBoostError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-40524e96ae70> in <module>
      1 # Funnel model application
----> 2 funnel_model = xgboost.Booster(model_file = project_directory + language+funnel_model_load)
      3 
      4 funnel_embedding = pickle.load(open(project_directory + language+funnel_vectorizer_load, 'rb'))
      5 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in __init__(self, params, cache, model_file)
   1324             self.__dict__.update(state)
   1325         elif isinstance(model_file, (STRING_TYPES, os.PathLike, bytearray)):
-> 1326             self.load_model(model_file)
   1327         elif model_file is None:
   1328             pass

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in load_model(self, fname)
   2160             fname = os.fspath(os.path.expanduser(fname))
   2161             _check_call(_LIB.XGBoosterLoadModel(
-> 2162                 self.handle, c_str(fname)))
   2163         elif isinstance(fname, bytearray):
   2164             buf = fname

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in _check_call(ret)
    216     """
    217     if ret != 0:
--> 218         raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
    219 
    220 

XGBoostError: bad allocation
```

Comment: Did you ever end up finding out a solution?

Comment: I can't quite remember but I think it was because I loaded a model made with an old version of XGboost whilst I was using a newer version.